# Unable to start my linux (cent OS ) machine in run level 5

Tags: linux, centos, x-windows, x-server

Suddenly my machine not working under run level 5 and it seems to be problem with xserver and it is saying that "in last 90 seconds xserver restarted 6 times and unable to start" and then just giving blank screen.So i changed the run level to 3 and using startx command i am managing to work now.can any one help me on this.......?

Answer (score 0):

Try backing up and removing /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
```

Then restart X.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with xorg.conf, then please follow this steps as:

> Xorg -configure
>
> mv ~/xorg.conf.new ~/xorg.conf
>
> Xinit or init 5

And If the problem is with  the Xserver itself, then you need to parse the log file to find out the cause.